# MVC4 TextBoxFor overwritting model property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Say I have a model:

```
public MyClass
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int ContentId {get;set;}
}
```

Let's assume I access the action of the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    mc.Id = 49;
    mc.ContentId = id;
    mc.Name = "Sample";
    return View("Create", mc);
}
```

"Create" view is strongly-typed with MyClass, and it has helper @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Id).

If I call action by invoking MyController/Create?id=15, textbox will show value 15 instead of 49. MVC will ignore my ID property set in action, and use the one from the query.

I find this rather odd considering this behavior is nowhere documented.

Any good comments on this?

Comment: Can you list the code for the view.  Otherwise, we can only guess as yo how you have used your model.  Also, you have used MVC4 in the question title but the question is tagged MVC3 (although it is not specific to either).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ModelState.Clear()` at the start of the Action

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Id)
```

Use:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Id)
```

And see if that gives you the functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem and is documented in various places.  A good example is here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx