# MVC Razor - query string impacting TextBoxFor and value of Model properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This is a bit odd (at least for me) so be prepared.  I have a simple object

```
public class User
{
  public FirstName { get; set; }
  public LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And a very simple View:

```
@Model User
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName)
@Html.Raw(Model.FirstName)
```

And the Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetUserInfo(Guid id, string firstName = "")
{
  User user;
  /* ... lookup the user instance ... */
  return View(user);
}
```

The Model I'm passing has FirstName = "John" and LastName = "Doe".  When I navigate to /Users/{Id}, both the textbox and Html.Raw value have a value of "John".  When I navigate to /Users/{Id}?firstName=, the value of the textbox is empty and the value of Html.Raw output is "John".  When I navigate to /Users/{Id}?firstName=Tom, the value of the textbox is "Tom" and the value of the Html.Raw is "John".

I've debugged both the Controller and the View.  The Model coming into the View has the correct properties.  My question:

Why is this happening?  I've never seen this before and can't reproduce it with other types of objects, Views, etc.

I'm using .NET 4.5 and MVC 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of searching, and posting here, I found a stackoverflow question which was almost identical.

[MVC4 TextBoxFor overwritting model property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716297/mvc4-textboxfor-overwritting-model-property)

To summarize [Aviran Cohen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358820/aviran-cohen)'s answer in the linked post, this problem can be resolved by adding the line `ModelState.Clear();` to the start of the affected controller action:

```
public ActionResult GetUserInfo(Guid id, string firstName = "")
{
  ModelState.Clear();
  User user;
  /* ... lookup the user instance ... */
  return View(user);
}
```